# Saving images in Winforms conversion problems

Tags: winforms

Hi I've been searching through many solutions for being able to store an image in winforms properties/settings but they have either been to advanced for me or are simply not working.

I have changed the type of the stored type to be a byte[] in the settings XML.

I have then tried to take an image that has been added by the user to then turn it into a byte[] using

```
  public void BitMapToArray(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Settings.Default[string.Format("Bitmap" + 1)] = imageConverter.ConvertTo(bitmap, typeof( byte[]));
    }
```

but I keep getting the error message of:
System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyWrongTypeException: 'The settings property 'Bitmap1' is of a non-compatible type.'

Even though I changed the type in XML and it is displaying as System.byte[] in the settings type.

I then went to try another alternative of trying to store the byte[] in a string but ran into different problems and feeling lost to which solution to try. Are there alternatives to storing an image as a byte or is there a reason why it is saying the property type of Bitmap1 isn't compatible when I've changed its type to Byte[]

Thanks

Comment: Hard to see how that could get to a good end.  Consider changing the type to String, use Convert.ToBase64String() when assigning it.

Comment: Why are trying to do this? Do you need to store user files or drawings? Try to explain what you need to accomplish insted of the solution you came up with.

Comment: @Jimi Hi Jimi you've made a good point my apologies, I'm basically creating a subliminal messaging program that quickly flashes text and images on the screen and wanting it so it saves the entered images and text. I've managed to store the text but struggling to find a way of saving the images for when the application is relaunched causing people to have to add the images they want to use again if that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. No need to apologise. People here ask questions to better understand the problem and then propose a viable solution. -- Do you mean you can't save the image(s) to disk (in whatever format)?

Comment: @Jimi Basically in properties and settings there is a section where variables can be saved even when the application is turned off and switched back on. And I can't find away of getting an image file to store in one of them.

Comment: Maybe you just want to save a File Path as a property. It's just a string. The actual Image will be on disk. Right? It could be a private storage area. Whatever fits the requirements